# Exiting From Oracle Apex PWA

Tags: oracle-apex

i am pretty new to oracle apex.

i have created oracle apex pwa.

now i want to have an exit button on home page to exit the application just like a native app.

Thanks in anticipation.
Regards
Athar

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i am using window.close() to close the app. it is working on desktop fine. but it is not working on mobile browsers

Answer (score 0):

Since the PWA is a webview, you could use a single line of JavaScript.

Create you button, add dynamic action with execute cliente side / JavaScript Code and add this.

```
window.close();
```

It works perfectly on the PWA I've installed in my Laptop